# Error - Expected content type text/json got text/html

Tags: php, ios, json

After trying the `Register` function in this app, it shows an error via a `UIAlert` that says

> Error
>
> Expected content type{["text/json", "application/json", "text/javascript" )}, got text/html.

How can one fix this type of error? After looking at the overview tab in Charles Proxy, it confirms that the `Content-Type` is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Charles proxy is also showing the `username` and `password` being entered but it seems it's not being executed.

This is the header used in the app

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

What is causing this error and how can it be solved?

```
//the web location of the service
#define kAPIHost @"http://192.168.1.3:8888"
#define kAPIPath @"iReporter/"
```

**Edit**

The app is supposed to register a user to a mysql database using `AFNetworking` in `iOS` and `Json` in its respective `php web service`

**lib.php (helps connect to mysql database)**

```
<?

//setup db connection
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysqli_select_db($link, "iReport");

//executes a given sql query with the params and returns an array as result
function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;

//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);

//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();

    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
}

//loads up the source image, resizes it and saves with -thumb in the file name
function thumb($srcFile, $sideInPx) {

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcFile);
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($sideInPx, $sideInPx);imagecopyresized($thumb,$image,0,0,0,0,$sideInPx,$sideInPx,$width,$height);

imagejpeg($thumb, str_replace(".jpg","-thumb.jpg",$srcFile), 85);

imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($image);
}

?>
```

**Index.php (the file the app connects to to call the php commands via AFNetworking Json response)**

```
<?
/* iReporter complete web demo project
 *
 * index.php takes care to check the "command" request
 * and call the proper API function to process the user request
 * 
 */

// this line starts the server session - that means the server will "remember" the user
// between different API calls - ie. once the user is authorized, he will stay logged in for a while
 session_start();

 // the require lines include the lib and api source files
require("lib.php");
require("api.php");

// this instructs the client (in this case the iPhone app) 
// that the server will output JSON data
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// the iPhone app sends over what "command" of the API it wants executed
// the tutorial covers "login","register","upload", "logout" and "stream"
// so using a switch statement for this taks makes most sense

// the functions you call inside the switch are found in the api.php file
switch ($_POST['command']) {
case "login":
    login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
    break;

case "register":
    register($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
    break;
```

**api.php (the file index.php connects to in order to call the server functions used in the app like login and register)**

```
<?

// helper function, which outputs error messages in JSON format
// so that the iPhone app can read them
// the function just takes in a dictionary with one key "error" and 
// encodes it in JSON, then prints it out and then exits the program
function errorJson($msg){
print json_encode(array('error'=>$msg));
exit();
}

// register API
function register($user, $pass) {

//check if username exists in the database (inside the "login" table)
$login = query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='%s' limit 1", $user);

if (count($login['result'])>0) {

    //the username exists, return error to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Username already exists');
}

//try to insert a new row in the "login" table with the given username and password
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);

if (!$result['error']) {
    //registration is successful, try to also directly login the new user
    login($user, $pass);
} else {
    //for some database reason the registration is unsuccessfull
    errorJson('Registration failed');
}

}

//login API
function login($user, $pass) {

// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

if (count($result['result'])>0) {
    // a row was found in the database for username/pass combination
    // save a simple flag in the user session, so the server remembers that the user is authorized
    $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];

    // print out the JSON of the user data to the iPhone app; it looks like this:
    // {IdUser:1, username: "Name"}
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    // no matching username/password was found in the login table
    errorJson('Authorization failed');
}

}

//upload API
function upload($id, $photoData, $title) {

// index.php passes as first parameter to this function $_SESSION['IdUser']
// $_SESSION['IdUser'] should contain the user id, if the user has already been authorized
// remember? you store the user id there in the login function
if (!$id) errorJson('Authorization required');

// check if there was no error during the file upload
if ($photoData['error']==0) {

    // insert the details about the photo to the "photos" table
    $result = query("INSERT INTO photos(IdUser,title) VALUES('%d','%s')", $id, $title);
    if (!$result['error']) {

        // fetch the active connection to the database (it's initialized automatically in lib.php)
        global $link;

        // get the last automatically generated ID in the photos table
        $IdPhoto = mysqli_insert_id($link);

        // move the temporarily stored file to a convenient location
        // your photo is automatically saved by PHP in a temp folder
        // you need to move it over yourself to your own "upload" folder
        if (move_uploaded_file($photoData['tmp_name'], "upload/".$IdPhoto.".jpg")) {

            // file moved, all good, generate thumbnail
            thumb("upload/".$IdPhoto.".jpg", 180);

            //just print out confirmation to the iPhone app
            print json_encode(array('successful'=>1));
        } else {
            //print out an error message to the iPhone app
            errorJson('Upload on server problem');
        };

    } else {
        errorJson('Upload database problem.'.$result['error']);
    }
} else {
    errorJson('Upload malfunction');
}
}

//logout API
function logout() {

// by saving an empty array to $_SESSION you are
// effectively destroying all the user session data
// ie. the server won't "remember" anymore anything about
// the current user
$_SESSION = array();

// and to make double-sure, there's also a built-in function 
// which wipes out the user session
session_destroy();
}

//stream API
//
// there are 2 ways to use the function:
// 1) don't pass any parameters - then the function will fetch all photos from the database
// 2) pass a photo id as a parameter - then the function will fetch the data of the requested photo
//
// Q: what "$IdPhoto=0" means? A: It's the PHP way to say "first param of the function is $IdPhoto, 
// if there's no param sent to the function - initialize $IdPhoto with a default value of 0"
function stream($IdPhoto=0) {

 if ($IdPhoto==0) {

    // load the last 50 photos from the "photos" table, also join the "login" so that you can fetch the 
    // usernames of the photos' authors
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50");

} else {
    //do the same as above, but just for the photo with the given id
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);
}

if (!$result['error']) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
}
?>
```

**Edit:** The error is shown when trying the register function from the apps login screen

Comment: Please add all the relevant code into the question itself and not as links off-site. You should also explain in more details what your code does. When do you get that message? In PHP? When your app sends a response or when it's making a request? It's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Form the error it seems like the server is not returning a json response as the app expected. Check the api code and make sure your api returns a json response in success and error scenarios

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited the question with a description of the apps desired abilities, and when the error message is shown.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr how?

Comment: honestly it seems trying the registration function is the easiest way but it still results in an error. I'm not sure how to get it to return json at this point

Comment: I'm not an expert in php, but I think you should use `echo json_encode($result);` or `echo errorJson()` in respective cases.

Comment: You should use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and building your queries like that.

Comment: **Warning:** _Never store passwords in clear text!_ Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Apart from the error message, does your code actually work? You can also use something like Postman to test your API. Also, make sure that there's no input what so ever before your result. No spaces or anything. That goes before any opening PHP tag and after any closing PHP-tag

Comment: Yes. It used to 6 months ago. Re-downloaded it. The tutorial is over 7 years old.

Comment: Source: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2893-how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-2-2 I say we download the completed tutorial together, roll up our sleeves and crack this as a team

Comment: _"Yes. It used to 6 months ago"_ - I'm not asking about 6 months ago. I'm asking about now. When you make a request to the API and you get that error message, has the code done what it suppose to do, apart from the error message?

Comment: No. It doesn't authorize the user. I see in Charles Proxy though that it the register command was called and shows the username and password values.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the short open tags `<?` anymore. You should use `<?php`. Short open tags have been disabled by default since a bunch of PHP-versions back.

Comment: wow. thast was it. Thank you so much!